# Adding Basemap on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, heat-map, basemap

I'm entirely new to QGIS and mapping services in general.

I add my data via CSV to create a new map layer (following the QGIS heatmap tutorial), I select Longitude in my X coordinate, and Latitude in Y, as shown below. If I don't do that, my data does not appear as it does when geocoded onto map services (such as BatchGeo). This seems counter-intuitive to me.

[image]

From there, I am attempting to add a basemap underneath my data points (ideally underneath a heatmap I've made - not sure how to do this either) but I seem to be having trouble. I have attempted using the OpenLayers PlugIn instructions found here (http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/basemap.php), but I keep getting an error when trying to add a Google or Bing Map. The message says "OpenLayers Plugin: Printing and rotating of Javascript API based layers is currently not supported!"

I have since found that QuickMap Services seems to be a preferred plugin, but I seem to have limited map options, and when i do pull in a map, my data points don't seem to show up where they need to be (looks like lat/long is reversed, which might relate back to how I import the data?).

Does anyone have any solutions for beginners for how to add a basemap or even alternate tutorials for creating heatmaps (on top of a basemap)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your points disappeared because you not specify Spatial Reference at last step adding csv to the map.

[image]

Your csv data are in WGS84 and base map (i.e. Google or Bing is in Web Mercator). Also you need to enable reproject on the fly.

[image]

Comment: NEVERMIND, I think this is working!!

Comment: The CRS of the CSV layer should be set to EPSG:4326, while the basemap layer and the project should be set to EPSG:3857.

Comment: Yes, thanks! That was exactly the issue. Thanks to you both!